# Vlookup and match

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, lookup

I'm trying to cross data to fill a sheet but I'm having some doubts.

I have a number a value in a sheet, and I want to complete it with data from another sheet.

For example:
[image: table example]

I want to complete Column C in sheet 1, with the age that appears in sheet 2 (no problem if it copy's the whole cell), but it's not in a specific column. I tried to use vlookup & match, and it's returning an error. a Vlookup the EAN column, and use match the specific string "Age:".

Can you help me? Am I using the right formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1, find the row you want to work on:  (Match on values in Column A)

```
=MATCH(Sheet1!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0)
```

Step 2, grab that entire row via `OFFSET` or `INDEX`:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$1:$1, MATCH(Sheet1!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0) - 1, 0)
```

Step 3, find the Age cell in that Row using `HLOOKUP` and Wildcards (`"*"`):

```
=HLOOKUP("Age:*", OFFSET(Sheet2!$1:$1, MATCH(Sheet1!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0) - 1, 0), 1, FALSE)
```

(Optional) Step 4, convert to number:

```
=0 + TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(HLOOKUP("Age:*", OFFSET(Sheet2!$1:$1, MATCH(Sheet1!$A2, Sheet2!$A:$A, 0) - 1, 0), 1, FALSE), "Age:", ""))
```

Then just drag that down from C2 to however many rows you need.  This will find the cell that starts with "Age:" in any column, `A:XFD`

Comment: Thank you so much @Chronocidal , it worked perfectly. I can use it and adapt to my needs. Initially, I had a problem implementing the formula in my workbook, but I created a whole new one with my data and it was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Found this [source](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list) where it explains how to do It. In your case it would be:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet 2!E2:CT2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(Sheet 2!E2:CT2),0))}
```

This is if your data starts on  Row 2 and as you said the age columns are between E:CT

Note how to insert the array formula as is explained on the post of the source.

Comment: Thank you @Damian , but that won't be workable, because I have 1300 rows to apply this. Well, got to work then. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many rows you have, you just need to drag the formula down it will work for all of them. Unless you mean by performance.

Comment: not by performance. But it's my fault, i didn't explain. I don't know where the "Age:" is located. Could be between E and CT; that's my current problem.